geolocation Service Fails to Query Location on Ubuntu 22.04 - "Failed to query location: Not Found
I'm experiencing an issue where the Your precise location could not be determined. This issue occurs consistently, and I'm unable to use location services in browsers like Firefox and Edge on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.
Details:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Browser(s): Firefox, Edge
Error Message:

Steps Taken:
Checked Network URL Configuration in Firefox: Verified the geo.provider.network.url setting, and it's correct.
Enabled Location Services in System Settings: Location services are enabled.
Firewall/Privacy Software: No firewall or privacy-focused software is blocking location services.
Tested in Other Browsers: The same issue occurs in Edge.
Restarted the System: No change after restarting.

how can I resolve this issue?

does this make tech easier article help understand any issues?
